# Redux initstate is not updating in the browser

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux

Im using next.js with react & redux-toolkit, redux-persist.

Whenever I add a new object in a slice file it is not shown in the redux logger.

```
const initState: promptsReducer = {
  first: {
    loading: false,
    apiExecutionStatus: API_PENDING_STATUS,
    error: null,
    data: [],
  },
  second: {},
  third: { // I added this object later to this slice
    loading: false,
    apiExecutionStatus: API_PENDING_STATUS,
    error: null,
    data: [],
  },
};
```

So here I add the third object while the server was running.

The server recompiled after adding this. But when I saw the redux-logger in the browser,
the REHYDRATION took pace but this object was not included.

I even tried to restart the server but it didn't work.

I thought this happens only in the localhost and deployed it to the real server through GitHub Actions. But even then it didn't work.

**Temporary solution:**

- I cleared site data in application tab and then reload the window
- Now this third object shows up in REHYDRATION

This is my rootReducer:

```
import { combineReducers, Reducer, AnyAction } from "redux";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import userAndCompanySlice from "./slices/userAndCompanySlice";
import promptsSlice from "./slices/promptsSlice";

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  userAndCompany: userAndCompanySlice.reducer,
  prompts: promptsSlice.reducer,
});

const rootReducer: Reducer = (state: RootState, action: AnyAction) => {
  if (action.type === "userAndCompany/logoutUser/fulfilled") {
    // this applies to all keys defined in persistConfig(s)
    storage.removeItem("persist:root");
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("dev_key");
    return appReducer(undefined, action);
  }
  return appReducer(state, action);
};

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof appReducer>;

export default rootReducer;
```

This is the store:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import { useDispatch as useDispatchRedux } from "react-redux";
import { ThunkDispatch as ReduxThunkDispatch } from "redux-thunk";
import { AnyAction } from "redux";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const createStore = (showLogger: boolean) =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer),
    devTools: false,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
      const middleware = getDefaultMiddleware({
        immutableCheck: false,
        serializableCheck: false,
      });
      if (showLogger) {
        middleware.push(logger);
      }
      return middleware;
    },
  });

const hideLogger =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" &&
  !process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL.includes("beta");

export const store = createStore(!hideLogger);

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatchRedux<AppDispatch>();
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export type ThunkDispatch = ReduxThunkDispatch<RootState, undefined, AnyAction>;
export const useDispatch: () => ThunkDispatch = useDispatchRedux;
```